# webcam has no voice

Tags: html, audio, webcam, microphone

I'm trying to do some web camera and web sound recording on browser.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/FDScP/ (you must open this on Chrome of version:21)

It require a cam and microphone as device, the cam is do well, but it's no voice by mic.

Answer (score 0):

None of the implementations of `getUserMedia` support voice yet. All they provide is access to the camera. Microphone access will come, eventually, but it's not here yet.

Comment: https://people.mozilla.com/~anarayanan/gum_test.html  this site show in nightly firefox, it can access voice by you mic. I want do it in Chrome.

Comment: Yes but as I said, it's not mainstream yet and is unlikely to be for a while. Flash is probably your best bet for now.

Comment: hey, the support has finally arrived, follow the documentation on http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled

Comment: That's only on one browser though.